# C# code for Search button

Tags: c#

I have a (Sql Server 2008) table called Courses with course_id,course_name and course_description as its fields
In the front end, I have a text box and a search button. In the text box, when I give a course name (even a part of it)..in the button click event, all the course names should show up.

How do I code this in C#? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/22/10000406.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select from sql table with where statement

eg, "whre course_name = '*a*'"

*a* means it will return all course name with a character a
for eg, matehmatics

can search for details about * thing in google.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use "LIKE" operator in sql command in order to list all the results *containing* the criteria.
Secondly, you should use SqlDataReader given that you are only retrieving values.
Thirdly, you should use a parameter in order to prevent sql injection.
Since you did not specify how you want to display the results, I populate a list from the results in my sample code below. I hope this helps you and future viewers.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Courses = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("the connection string here");
        SqlDataReader reader;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT courseName, courseDescription FROM db.Courses WHERE CourseName LIKE %@CourseName%";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", textBox1.Text);

        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string course = reader["CourseName"].ToString();
            course += ", " + reader["CourseDescription"].ToString();
            Courses.Add(course);
        }
        reader.Close();

        foreach (string course in Courses)
        {
            //wherever and however you would like to display
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Processor,HDD,RAM,Display,Graphics,OS,processor,hdd,ram,display,os,opticaldrive,warranty,price,other,graphics,images,Warranty,Price,Images,other from System where CompanyName='"+companyname.Text+"'",con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        processor.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Really not a good solution! Actually it's terrible, braking all the rules.

Comment: This is a textbook example of everything you *shouldn't* do.